# Div interference with other divs

Tags: css, html

I have

```
#nameleft {
    margin-left: 170px; 
    margin-top: -170px; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;"
}
#nameright {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    margin-top: 180px; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;"
}
#namecenter {
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;"
}
```

But the namecenter one interferes with the nameright and nameleft divs. How can I make it that namecenter just ignores everything on the page so I can put it where ever i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it absolute, and it will be positioned relative to the closest (going up the tree) element with a position that isn't `static`: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPN5R/)

```
position: absolute;
top: 0; /* Distance from top of this element to top of positioning element */
left: 400px; /* Distance from left of this element to left of positioning element */
```

Comment: Silly me I just forgot to add <font style="position: absolute;"> too the the letters inside the div hahaha

Comment: @Friedpanseller FYI, the `<font>` tag was deprecated as of HTML 4.0.1, use `<span>` with CSS.